# Swipe to delete a ListView Item

Tags: android

I saw the demo of swipe to delete in **Google android i/o 2013**, under **A moving experience**:

https://developers.google.com/events/io/sessions/326431311

The code is too complicated and *Romain Guy* says **Don't worry we will give you the code**. Where is the code, I searched everywhere.

Where can i find the code?

Also I had a doubt that how will a user know he/she can swipe the item to delete? Because though I try hard and implement this animation, its useless if no one uses.

Thank You

Comment: Just use **EnhancedListView**.  it's the only way to go.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's the sourcee code (for android 4.1 i guess).

http://developer.android.com/shareables/devbytes/ListViewRemovalAnimation.zip

You can also look at the blog. It changed since i looked last time (updated).

http://www.graphics-geek.blogspot.in/

To see the older posts scroll down the page. Click on older posts and you will see the Animating Listview deletion. The codes and the videos are posted on the blog.

ListViewRemovalAnimation.java

```
public class ListViewRemovalAnimation extends Activity {

    StableArrayAdapter mAdapter;
    ListView mListView;
    BackgroundContainer mBackgroundContainer;
    boolean mSwiping = false;
    boolean mItemPressed = false;
    HashMap<Long, Integer> mItemIdTopMap = new HashMap<Long, Integer>();

    private static final int SWIPE_DURATION = 250;
    private static final int MOVE_DURATION = 150;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_view_deletion);

        mBackgroundContainer = (BackgroundContainer) findViewById(R.id.listViewBackground);
        mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        android.util.Log.d("Debug", "d=" + mListView.getDivider());
        final ArrayList<String> cheeseList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Cheeses.sCheeseStrings.length; ++i) {
            cheeseList.add(Cheeses.sCheeseStrings[i]);
        }
        mAdapter = new StableArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.opaque_text_view, cheeseList,
                mTouchListener);
        mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    /**
     * Handle touch events to fade/move dragged items as they are swiped out
     */
    private View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener = new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float mDownX;
        private int mSwipeSlop = -1;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(final View v, MotionEvent event) {
            if (mSwipeSlop < 0) {
                mSwipeSlop = ViewConfiguration.get(ListViewRemovalAnimation.this).
                        getScaledTouchSlop();
            }
            switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                if (mItemPressed) {
                    // Multi-item swipes not handled
                    return false;
                }
                mItemPressed = true;
                mDownX = event.getX();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                v.setAlpha(1);
                v.setTranslationX(0);
                mItemPressed = false;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                {
                    float x = event.getX() + v.getTranslationX();
                    float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                    float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                    if (!mSwiping) {
                        if (deltaXAbs > mSwipeSlop) {
                            mSwiping = true;
                            mListView.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
                            mBackgroundContainer.showBackground(v.getTop(), v.getHeight());
                        }
                    }
                    if (mSwiping) {
                        v.setTranslationX((x - mDownX));
                        v.setAlpha(1 - deltaXAbs / v.getWidth());
                    }
                }
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                {
                    // User let go - figure out whether to animate the view out, or back into place
                    if (mSwiping) {
                        float x = event.getX() + v.getTranslationX();
                        float deltaX = x - mDownX;
                        float deltaXAbs = Math.abs(deltaX);
                        float fractionCovered;
                        float endX;
                        float endAlpha;
                        final boolean remove;
                        if (deltaXAbs > v.getWidth() / 4) {
                            // Greater than a quarter of the width - animate it out
                            fractionCovered = deltaXAbs / v.getWidth();
                            endX = deltaX < 0 ? -v.getWidth() : v.getWidth();
                            endAlpha = 0;
                            remove = true;
                        } else {
                            // Not far enough - animate it back
                            fractionCovered = 1 - (deltaXAbs / v.getWidth());
                            endX = 0;
                            endAlpha = 1;
                            remove = false;
                        }
                        // Animate position and alpha of swiped item
                        // NOTE: This is a simplified version of swipe behavior, for the
                        // purposes of this demo about animation. A real version should use
                        // velocity (via the VelocityTracker class) to send the item off or
                        // back at an appropriate speed.
                        long duration = (int) ((1 - fractionCovered) * SWIPE_DURATION);
                        mListView.setEnabled(false);
                        v.animate().setDuration(duration).
                                alpha(endAlpha).translationX(endX).
                                withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void run() {
                                        // Restore animated values
                                        v.setAlpha(1);
                                        v.setTranslationX(0);
                                        if (remove) {
                                            animateRemoval(mListView, v);
                                        } else {
                                            mBackgroundContainer.hideBackground();
                                            mSwiping = false;
                                            mListView.setEnabled(true);
                                        }
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                }
                mItemPressed = false;
                break;
            default: 
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
    };

    /**
     * This method animates all other views in the ListView container (not including ignoreView)
     * into their final positions. It is called after ignoreView has been removed from the
     * adapter, but before layout has been run. The approach here is to figure out where
     * everything is now, then allow layout to run, then figure out where everything is after
     * layout, and then to run animations between all of those start/end positions.
     */
    private void animateRemoval(final ListView listview, View viewToRemove) {
        int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); ++i) {
            View child = listview.getChildAt(i);
            if (child != viewToRemove) {
                int position = firstVisiblePosition + i;
                long itemId = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
                mItemIdTopMap.put(itemId, child.getTop());
            }
        }
        // Delete the item from the adapter
        int position = mListView.getPositionForView(viewToRemove);
        mAdapter.remove(mAdapter.getItem(position));

        final ViewTreeObserver observer = listview.getViewTreeObserver();
        observer.addOnPreDrawListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener() {
            public boolean onPreDraw() {
                observer.removeOnPreDrawListener(this);
                boolean firstAnimation = true;
                int firstVisiblePosition = listview.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                for (int i = 0; i < listview.getChildCount(); ++i) {
                    final View child = listview.getChildAt(i);
                    int position = firstVisiblePosition + i;
                    long itemId = mAdapter.getItemId(position);
                    Integer startTop = mItemIdTopMap.get(itemId);
                    int top = child.getTop();
                    if (startTop != null) {
                        if (startTop != top) {
                            int delta = startTop - top;
                            child.setTranslationY(delta);
                            child.animate().setDuration(MOVE_DURATION).translationY(0);
                            if (firstAnimation) {
                                child.animate().withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                        mBackgroundContainer.hideBackground();
                                        mSwiping = false;
                                        mListView.setEnabled(true);
                                    }
                                });
                                firstAnimation = false;
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                        // Animate new views along with the others. The catch is that they did not
                        // exist in the start state, so we must calculate their starting position
                        // based on neighboring views.
                        int childHeight = child.getHeight() + listview.getDividerHeight();
                        startTop = top + (i > 0 ? childHeight : -childHeight);
                        int delta = startTop - top;
                        child.setTranslationY(delta);
                        child.animate().setDuration(MOVE_DURATION).translationY(0);
                        if (firstAnimation) {
                            child.animate().withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                                public void run() {
                                    mBackgroundContainer.hideBackground();
                                    mSwiping = false;
                                    mListView.setEnabled(true);
                                }
                            });
                            firstAnimation = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
                mItemIdTopMap.clear();
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

}
```

StableArrayAdapter.java

```
public class StableArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    HashMap<String, Integer> mIdMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    View.OnTouchListener mTouchListener;

    public StableArrayAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            List<String> objects, View.OnTouchListener listener) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
        mTouchListener = listener;
        for (int i = 0; i < objects.size(); ++i) {
            mIdMap.put(objects.get(i), i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        String item = getItem(position);
        return mIdMap.get(item);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
        if (view != convertView) {
            // Add touch listener to every new view to track swipe motion
            view.setOnTouchListener(mTouchListener);
        }
        return view;
    }

}
```

Cheese.java

```
public class Cheeses {

    public static final String[] sCheeseStrings = {
            "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
            "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale",
            "Aisy Cendre", "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Alverca", "Ambert", "American Cheese",
            "Ami du Chambertin", "Anejo Enchilado", "Anneau du Vic-Bilh", "Anthoriro", "Appenzell",
            "Aragon", "Ardi Gasna", "Ardrahan", "Armenian String", "Aromes au Gene de Marc",
            "Asadero", "Asiago", "Aubisque Pyrenees", "Autun", "Avaxtskyr", "Baby Swiss",
            "Babybel", "Baguette Laonnaise", "Bakers", "Baladi", "Balaton", "Bandal", "Banon",
            "Barry's Bay Cheddar", "Basing", "Basket Cheese", "Bath Cheese", "Bavarian Bergkase",
            "Baylough", "Beaufort", "Beauvoorde", "Beenleigh Blue", "Beer Cheese", "Bel Paese",
            "Bergader", "Bergere Bleue", "Berkswell", "Beyaz Peynir", "Bierkase", "Bishop Kennedy",
            "Blarney", "Bleu d'Auvergne", "Bleu de Gex", "Bleu de Laqueuille",
            "Bleu de Septmoncel", "Bleu Des Causses", "Blue", "Blue Castello", "Blue Rathgore",
            "Blue Vein (Australian)", "Blue Vein Cheeses", "Bocconcini", "Bocconcini (Australian)",
            "Boeren Leidenkaas", "Bonchester", "Bosworth", "Bougon", "Boule Du Roves",
            "Boulette d'Avesnes", "Boursault", "Boursin", "Bouyssou", "Bra", "Braudostur",
            "Breakfast Cheese", "Brebis du Lavort", "Brebis du Lochois", "Brebis du Puyfaucon",
            "Bresse Bleu", "Brick", "Brie", "Brie de Meaux", "Brie de Melun", "Brillat-Savarin",
            "Brin", "Brin d' Amour", "Brin d'Amour", "Brinza (Burduf Brinza)",
            "Briquette de Brebis", "Briquette du Forez", "Broccio", "Broccio Demi-Affine",
            "Brousse du Rove", "Bruder Basil", "Brusselae Kaas (Fromage de Bruxelles)", "Bryndza",
            "Buchette d'Anjou", "Buffalo", "Burgos", "Butte", "Butterkase", "Button (Innes)",
            "Buxton Blue", "Cabecou", "Caboc", "Cabrales", "Cachaille", "Caciocavallo", "Caciotta",
            "Caerphilly", "Cairnsmore", "Calenzana", "Cambazola", "Camembert de Normandie",
            "Canadian Cheddar", "Canestrato", "Cantal", "Caprice des Dieux", "Capricorn Goat",
            "Capriole Banon", "Carre de l'Est", "Casciotta di Urbino", "Cashel Blue", "Castellano",
            "Castelleno", "Castelmagno", "Castelo Branco", "Castigliano", "Cathelain",
            "Celtic Promise", "Cendre d'Olivet", "Cerney", "Chabichou", "Chabichou du Poitou",
            "Chabis de Gatine", "Chaource", "Charolais", "Chaumes", "Cheddar",
            "Cheddar Clothbound", "Cheshire", "Chevres", "Chevrotin des Aravis", "Chontaleno",
            "Civray", "Coeur de Camembert au Calvados", "Coeur de Chevre", "Colby", "Cold Pack",
            "Comte", "Coolea", "Cooleney", "Coquetdale", "Corleggy", "Cornish Pepper",
            "Cotherstone", "Cotija", "Cottage Cheese", "Cottage Cheese (Australian)",
            "Cougar Gold", "Coulommiers", "Coverdale", "Crayeux de Roncq", "Cream Cheese",
            "Cream Havarti", "Crema Agria", "Crema Mexicana", "Creme Fraiche", "Crescenza",
            "Croghan", "Crottin de Chavignol", "Crottin du Chavignol", "Crowdie", "Crowley",
            "Cuajada", "Curd", "Cure Nantais", "Curworthy", "Cwmtawe Pecorino",
            "Cypress Grove Chevre", "Danablu (Danish Blue)", "Danbo", "Danish Fontina",
            "Daralagjazsky", "Dauphin", "Delice des Fiouves", "Denhany Dorset Drum", "Derby",
            "Dessertnyj Belyj", "Devon Blue", "Devon Garland", "Dolcelatte", "Doolin",
            "Doppelrhamstufel", "Dorset Blue Vinney", "Double Gloucester", "Double Worcester",
            "Dreux a la Feuille", "Dry Jack", "Duddleswell", "Dunbarra", "Dunlop", "Dunsyre Blue",
            "Duroblando", "Durrus", "Dutch Mimolette (Commissiekaas)", "Edam", "Edelpilz",
            "Emental Grand Cru", "Emlett", "Emmental", "Epoisses de Bourgogne", "Esbareich",
            "Esrom", "Etorki", "Evansdale Farmhouse Brie", "Evora De L'Alentejo", "Exmoor Blue",
            "Explorateur", "Feta", "Feta (Australian)", "Figue", "Filetta", "Fin-de-Siecle",
            "Finlandia Swiss", "Finn", "Fiore Sardo", "Fleur du Maquis", "Flor de Guia",
            "Flower Marie", "Folded", "Folded cheese with mint", "Fondant de Brebis",
            "Fontainebleau", "Fontal", "Fontina Val d'Aosta", "Formaggio di capra", "Fougerus",
            "Four Herb Gouda", "Fourme d' Ambert", "Fourme de Haute Loire", "Fourme de Montbrison",
            "Fresh Jack", "Fresh Mozzarella", "Fresh Ricotta", "Fresh Truffles", "Fribourgeois",
            "Friesekaas", "Friesian", "Friesla", "Frinault", "Fromage a Raclette", "Fromage Corse",
            "Fromage de Montagne de Savoie", "Fromage Frais", "Fruit Cream Cheese",
            "Frying Cheese", "Fynbo", "Gabriel", "Galette du Paludier", "Galette Lyonnaise",
            "Galloway Goat's Milk Gems", "Gammelost", "Gaperon a l'Ail", "Garrotxa", "Gastanberra",
            "Geitost", "Gippsland Blue", "Gjetost", "Gloucester", "Golden Cross", "Gorgonzola",
            "Gornyaltajski", "Gospel Green", "Gouda", "Goutu", "Gowrie", "Grabetto", "Graddost",
            "Grafton Village Cheddar", "Grana", "Grana Padano", "Grand Vatel",
            "Grataron d' Areches", "Gratte-Paille", "Graviera", "Greuilh", "Greve",
            "Gris de Lille", "Gruyere", "Gubbeen", "Guerbigny", "Halloumi",
            "Halloumy (Australian)", "Haloumi-Style Cheese", "Harbourne Blue", "Havarti",
            "Heidi Gruyere", "Hereford Hop", "Herrgardsost", "Herriot Farmhouse", "Herve",
            "Hipi Iti", "Hubbardston Blue Cow", "Hushallsost", "Iberico", "Idaho Goatster",
            "Idiazabal", "Il Boschetto al Tartufo", "Ile d'Yeu", "Isle of Mull", "Jarlsberg",
            "Jermi Tortes", "Jibneh Arabieh", "Jindi Brie", "Jubilee Blue", "Juustoleipa",
            "Kadchgall", "Kaseri", "Kashta", "Kefalotyri", "Kenafa", "Kernhem", "Kervella Affine",
            "Kikorangi", "King Island Cape Wickham Brie", "King River Gold", "Klosterkaese",
            "Knockalara", "Kugelkase", "L'Aveyronnais", "L'Ecir de l'Aubrac", "La Taupiniere",
            "La Vache Qui Rit", "Laguiole", "Lairobell", "Lajta", "Lanark Blue", "Lancashire",
            "Langres", "Lappi", "Laruns", "Lavistown", "Le Brin", "Le Fium Orbo", "Le Lacandou",
            "Le Roule", "Leafield", "Lebbene", "Leerdammer", "Leicester", "Leyden", "Limburger",
            "Lincolnshire Poacher", "Lingot Saint Bousquet d'Orb", "Liptauer", "Little Rydings",
            "Livarot", "Llanboidy", "Llanglofan Farmhouse", "Loch Arthur Farmhouse",
            "Loddiswell Avondale", "Longhorn", "Lou Palou", "Lou Pevre", "Lyonnais", "Maasdam",
            "Macconais", "Mahoe Aged Gouda", "Mahon", "Malvern", "Mamirolle", "Manchego",
            "Manouri", "Manur", "Marble Cheddar", "Marbled Cheeses", "Maredsous", "Margotin",
            "Maribo", "Maroilles", "Mascares", "Mascarpone", "Mascarpone (Australian)",
            "Mascarpone Torta", "Matocq", "Maytag Blue", "Meira", "Menallack Farmhouse",
            "Menonita", "Meredith Blue", "Mesost", "Metton (Cancoillotte)", "Meyer Vintage Gouda",
            "Mihalic Peynir", "Milleens", "Mimolette", "Mine-Gabhar", "Mini Baby Bells", "Mixte",
            "Molbo", "Monastery Cheeses", "Mondseer", "Mont D'or Lyonnais", "Montasio",
            "Monterey Jack", "Monterey Jack Dry", "Morbier", "Morbier Cru de Montagne",
            "Mothais a la Feuille", "Mozzarella", "Mozzarella (Australian)",
            "Mozzarella di Bufala", "Mozzarella Fresh, in water", "Mozzarella Rolls", "Munster",
            "Murol", "Mycella", "Myzithra", "Naboulsi", "Nantais", "Neufchatel",
            "Neufchatel (Australian)", "Niolo", "Nokkelost", "Northumberland", "Oaxaca",
            "Olde York", "Olivet au Foin", "Olivet Bleu", "Olivet Cendre",
            "Orkney Extra Mature Cheddar", "Orla", "Oschtjepka", "Ossau Fermier", "Ossau-Iraty",
            "Oszczypek", "Oxford Blue", "P'tit Berrichon", "Palet de Babligny", "Paneer", "Panela",
            "Pannerone", "Pant ys Gawn", "Parmesan (Parmigiano)", "Parmigiano Reggiano",
            "Pas de l'Escalette", "Passendale", "Pasteurized Processed", "Pate de Fromage",
            "Patefine Fort", "Pave d'Affinois", "Pave d'Auge", "Pave de Chirac", "Pave du Berry",
            "Pecorino", "Pecorino in Walnut Leaves", "Pecorino Romano", "Peekskill Pyramid",
            "Pelardon des Cevennes", "Pelardon des Corbieres", "Penamellera", "Penbryn",
            "Pencarreg", "Perail de Brebis", "Petit Morin", "Petit Pardou", "Petit-Suisse",
            "Picodon de Chevre", "Picos de Europa", "Piora", "Pithtviers au Foin",
            "Plateau de Herve", "Plymouth Cheese", "Podhalanski", "Poivre d'Ane", "Polkolbin",
            "Pont l'Eveque", "Port Nicholson", "Port-Salut", "Postel", "Pouligny-Saint-Pierre",
            "Pourly", "Prastost", "Pressato", "Prince-Jean", "Processed Cheddar", "Provolone",
            "Provolone (Australian)", "Pyengana Cheddar", "Pyramide", "Quark",
            "Quark (Australian)", "Quartirolo Lombardo", "Quatre-Vents", "Quercy Petit",
            "Queso Blanco", "Queso Blanco con Frutas --Pina y Mango", "Queso de Murcia",
            "Queso del Montsec", "Queso del Tietar", "Queso Fresco", "Queso Fresco (Adobera)",
            "Queso Iberico", "Queso Jalapeno", "Queso Majorero", "Queso Media Luna",
            "Queso Para Frier", "Queso Quesadilla", "Rabacal", "Raclette", "Ragusano", "Raschera",
            "Reblochon", "Red Leicester", "Regal de la Dombes", "Reggianito", "Remedou",
            "Requeson", "Richelieu", "Ricotta", "Ricotta (Australian)", "Ricotta Salata", "Ridder",
            "Rigotte", "Rocamadour", "Rollot", "Romano", "Romans Part Dieu", "Roncal", "Roquefort",
            "Roule", "Rouleau De Beaulieu", "Royalp Tilsit", "Rubens", "Rustinu", "Saaland Pfarr",
            "Saanenkaese", "Saga", "Sage Derby", "Sainte Maure", "Saint-Marcellin",
            "Saint-Nectaire", "Saint-Paulin", "Salers", "Samso", "San Simon", "Sancerre",
            "Sap Sago", "Sardo", "Sardo Egyptian", "Sbrinz", "Scamorza", "Schabzieger", "Schloss",
            "Selles sur Cher", "Selva", "Serat", "Seriously Strong Cheddar", "Serra da Estrela",
            "Sharpam", "Shelburne Cheddar", "Shropshire Blue", "Siraz", "Sirene", "Smoked Gouda",
            "Somerset Brie", "Sonoma Jack", "Sottocenare al Tartufo", "Soumaintrain",
            "Sourire Lozerien", "Spenwood", "Sraffordshire Organic", "St. Agur Blue Cheese",
            "Stilton", "Stinking Bishop", "String", "Sussex Slipcote", "Sveciaost", "Swaledale",
            "Sweet Style Swiss", "Swiss", "Syrian (Armenian String)", "Tala", "Taleggio", "Tamie",
            "Tasmania Highland Chevre Log", "Taupiniere", "Teifi", "Telemea", "Testouri",
            "Tete de Moine", "Tetilla", "Texas Goat Cheese", "Tibet", "Tillamook Cheddar",
            "Tilsit", "Timboon Brie", "Toma", "Tomme Brulee", "Tomme d'Abondance",
            "Tomme de Chevre", "Tomme de Romans", "Tomme de Savoie", "Tomme des Chouans", "Tommes",
            "Torta del Casar", "Toscanello", "Touree de L'Aubier", "Tourmalet",
            "Trappe (Veritable)", "Trois Cornes De Vendee", "Tronchon", "Trou du Cru", "Truffe",
            "Tupi", "Turunmaa", "Tymsboro", "Tyn Grug", "Tyning", "Ubriaco", "Ulloa",
            "Vacherin-Fribourgeois", "Valencay", "Vasterbottenost", "Venaco", "Vendomois",
            "Vieux Corse", "Vignotte", "Vulscombe", "Waimata Farmhouse Blue",
            "Washed Rind Cheese (Australian)", "Waterloo", "Weichkaese", "Wellington",
            "Wensleydale", "White Stilton", "Whitestone Farmhouse", "Wigmore", "Woodside Cabecou",
            "Xanadu", "Xynotyro", "Yarg Cornish", "Yarra Valley Pyramid", "Yorkshire Blue",
            "Zamorano", "Zanetti Grana Padano", "Zanetti Parmigiano Reggiano"
    };

}
```

BackgroundContainer.java

```
public class BackgroundContainer extends FrameLayout {

    boolean mShowing = false;
    Drawable mShadowedBackground;
    int mOpenAreaTop, mOpenAreaBottom, mOpenAreaHeight;
    boolean mUpdateBounds = false;

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        init();
    }

    public BackgroundContainer(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        mShadowedBackground =
                getContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.shadowed_background);
    }

    public void showBackground(int top, int bottom) {
        setWillNotDraw(false);
        mOpenAreaTop = top;
        mOpenAreaHeight = bottom;
        mShowing = true;
        mUpdateBounds = true;
    }

    public void hideBackground() {
        setWillNotDraw(true);
        mShowing = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        if (mShowing) {
                if (mUpdateBounds) {
                mShadowedBackground.setBounds(0, 0, getWidth(), mOpenAreaHeight);
                }
            canvas.save();
            canvas.translate(0, mOpenAreaTop);
            mShadowedBackground.draw(canvas);
            canvas.restore();
        }
    }

}
```

Layout files

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ListViewAnimations" >

    <view
        class="com.example.android.listviewremovalanimation.BackgroundContainer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listViewBackground">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview"
            android:divider="@null"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </view>

</LinearLayout>
```

opaque_text_view.xml

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/tv_background_with_divider"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingStart"
    android:paddingEnd="?android:attr/listPreferredItemPaddingEnd"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
/>
```

Answer (score 3):

From my point of view this link is better than all others ..

[SwipeToDismissUndoList](https://github.com/timroes/SwipeToDismissUndoList)

#### Note :

> **SwipeToDismissUndoList** library is deprecated in favor of  **EnhancedListView**, which is also deprecated in favour of **RecyclerView**
>
> **RecyclerView** is part of the **support library**, so it is **backward compatible** to API level 7.

[EnhancedListView](https://github.com/timroes/EnhancedListView)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thnxs for the suggestion, i will take care of it. @nathanchere